# What is the connection between Jordan Canonical Form and minimal polynomial?

Tags: linear-algebra, jordan-normal-form

I saw a bunch of examples of Jordan Canonical Form and how it is related to the minimal polynomial. I have noticed the following patterns:

Let $A$ be a matrix and $\lambda_1,\dots,\lambda_k$ be the eigenvalues of $A$.

(1). The number of Jordan blocks corresponding to the eigenvalue $\lambda_j$ is the dimension of the eigenspace of $\lambda_j$.

(2). The power of $(x-\lambda_j)$ in the minimal polynomial of $A$ is the size of the largest Jordan block corresponding to $\lambda_j$.

Are (1) and (2) true in general?

Comment: If $B$ is upper triangular and also zero on the diagonal then what is its minimal polynomial ?

Comment: Yes, they are true in general.

Answer (score 10):

Yes, both of these are true in general.

To see that (1) is true, note that if $J$ is in Jordan form, then 
$\dim(\ker(J - \lambda I))$ will simply be the number of $0$-columns in $J - \lambda I$.  Note that these $0$-columns only occur at the start of any Jordan block.

To see that (2) is true, note that for any polynomial $p$,
$$
p(J) = p(J_1) \oplus p(J_2)  \oplus \cdots \oplus p(J_m)
$$
where each $J_i$ denotes are Jordan block, and $\oplus$ denotes a [diagonal direct sum](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MatrixDirectSum.html).  Note that if $J$ is the Jordan block of size $q$ associated with $\lambda$, then we will have
$$
p(J) = 0 \iff (x - \lambda)^q \mid p(x)
$$